# How do we prove the proposed expression is nonnegative?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

So the expression which I am interested in is given by
\begin{align*}
f(b,\theta) = \frac{2b-1}{b\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2} + \theta}} + \frac{\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2} + \theta} - 1}{2b^{2}(\theta - 1)}
\end{align*}
where $b\in(0,1]$, $\theta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\theta\neq 1$.

It is part of my research project and I would like to know a good way to approach it.

Any hint is appreciated.

**EDIT**

According to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282b-1%29%2F%28b*sqrt%28%281-x%29%282b-1%29%5E2%20%2B%20x%29%29%20%2B%20%28sqrt%28%281-x%29%282b-1%29%5E2%20%2B%20x%29%20-%201%29%2F%282b%5E2%28x-1%29%29%20%3E%3D%200%2C%20x%20%3E0), the solution is given by $0 < b \leq 1$ when $\theta > 0$.

Comment: Checking with WolframAlpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D+%282b-1%29%2F%28b+sqrt%28%281-%5Ctheta%29%282b-1%29%5E2+%2B+%5Ctheta%29%29+%2B+%28sqrt%28%281-%5Ctheta%29%282b-1%29%5E2+%2B+%5Ctheta%29+-+1%29%2F%282b%5E2%28%5Ctheta+-+1%29%29+) it appears that in your interval $0\lt b \le \frac12 \land \theta=0$. I would try substituting $\theta=0$ and seeing how that simplifies the equation. Then you can try $b$-values but the only integer $b$-values are negative.

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to include the WA result. Interestingly, I got the solution $0 < b\leq 1$ for $\theta > 0$.

Comment: I did the edits in WA  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D+%282b-1%29%2F%28b+sqrt%28%281-0%29%282b-1%29%5E2+%2B+0%29%29+%2B+%28sqrt%28%281-0%29%282b-1%29%5E2+%2B+0%29+-+1%29%2F%282b%5E2%280-+1%29%29+) and I still get $0 < b < \frac12$

Comment: The thing is that $\theta > 0$. You have plugged in $\theta = 0$.

Comment: But the only solutions WA gave indicated $\theta=0$. I have tried without success to put this equation into a spreadsheet but maybe you can doe better than I did. Do it a piece at a time. I tried the whole, then the half, then ran out of time. I have to go. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $A = (1-\theta)(2b-1)^2 + \theta$.

Since $(2b-1)^2 \le 1$, we have $A \ge (1-\theta)(2b-1)^2 + \theta (2b-1)^2 = (2b-1)^2$.

We have
\begin{align}
f(b, \theta) &= \frac{2b-1}{b\sqrt{A}} + \frac{\sqrt{A} - 1}{2b^2(\theta - 1)} \\
&= \frac{2b-1}{b\sqrt{A}} + \frac{A - 1}{2b^2(\theta - 1)(\sqrt{A} + 1)}\\
&= \frac{2b-1}{b\sqrt{A}} + \frac{2(1-b)}{b(\sqrt{A} + 1)}\\
&= \frac{2b - 1 + \sqrt{A}}{b\sqrt{A}(\sqrt{A} + 1)}\\
&\ge \frac{2b - 1 + \sqrt{(2b-1)^2}}{b\sqrt{A}(\sqrt{A} + 1)}\\
&\ge 0.
\end{align}
We are done.

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(b,\theta)\geq 0
$$
\begin{align*}
 \implies\frac{2b-1}{b\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2} + \theta}} + \frac{\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2} + \theta} - 1}{2b^{2}(\theta - 1)}&\geq 0\\ \\
 \implies 2b-1+\frac{\left(b\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2}+\theta}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2} + \theta} - 1\right)}{2b^{2}(\theta - 1)}&\geq 0\\\\
 \implies 2b-1+\frac{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2}+\theta-\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2}+\theta}}{2b(\theta-1)}&\geq 0\\
 \implies 2b(\theta-1)(2b-1)+(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2}+\theta-\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2}+\theta}&\geq 0\\\\
\implies 2b\theta-2b+1-\sqrt{(1-\theta)(2b-1)^{2}+\theta}&\geq 0
\end{align*}
This implies the following :

- **First Case** : $b=0$ which is not the case since $b\in(0,1]$.
- **Second Case** : $0<b \leq 0.5$ and $\theta >\displaystyle \frac{4b^{2}-4 b+1 }{4  b^{2}-4  b}$
- **Third Case** : $0.5<b\leq 1$ and $\theta> 0$

Hence it follows that $\forall b\in(0,1]$ and $\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with $\theta\neq 1$ we have that $f$ is non-negative.

Comment: In the last 3rd $\Longrightarrow$, did you multiply $2b(\theta - 1)$ on both sides? But $2b(\theta - 1)$ can be negative.